# CSS not loaded when I open a local HTML file on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

My website works perfectly on desktop and it's 100% responsive (I used media queries). When I open the html on my mobile (through Chrome, Opera or HTML Viewer) it does not load any CSS property, not even the most basics like background color.
I put this line in my header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
```

but the problem persists...

*Mobile: Honor 6X*

*Android 7.0*

*EMUI 5.0.3*

---

Edit:
[image]
Here is a sample of my code:
As you can see, there are several files but I will give you `common.html` and `common.css`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
    <title>off</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/variables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/common.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Chettan" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>


  <body id="aBody" class="light-mode">

    <div id="container">

      <header>

        <nav id="navbar">
          <div class="icon"><img src="../img/h.png" alt="h"></div>
          <div class="icon"><img src="../img/m.png" alt="m"></div>
          <div class="icon"><img src="../img/r.png" alt="r"></div>
          <div class="icon"><img src="../img/p.png" alt="p"></div>
          <div class="icon" id="settingsBtn"><img src="../img/settings_flat.png" alt="settings"></div>
        </nav>

        <div id="myModal" class="modal">

         <div id="modalContent" class="modal-content light-mode">

           <span class="close">&times;</span>
           <h1>Settings</h1>
           <br>
           <p>Color:</p>
           <div id="colors">
            <div id="A" onclick="changeColor(this)" class="color-change"></div>
            <div id="B" onclick="changeColor(this)" class="color-change"></div>
            <div id="C" onclick="changeColor(this)" class="color-change"></div>
            <div id="D" onclick="changeColor(this)" class="color-change"></div>
          </div>

           <p>Dark mode:</p>

           <input onclick="invertMode()" type="checkbox" id="switch" />
           <label for="switch"></label>

         </div>

        </div>

      </header>

  </body>

  <script src="../js/modal.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="../js/darkmode.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="../js/changecolor.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</html>
```

Css:

```
*{
  margin:0;
  font-family: var(--main-font);
}

/* -- Navigation Bar -- */
nav{
  height: 100vh;
  width: var(--navbar-dimension);
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--navbar-top), var(--navbar-bottom));
  position: fixed;
  transition: top var(--transition-speed);
}

nav:after{
  content:"";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
/* -- Icons -- */
.icon > img{
  height: var(--icon-dimension);
  width: auto;
}

.icon{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--plus-h);
  text-align:center;
  transition: background-color var(--transition-speed);

}

.icon:hover{
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.icon:left{
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

/* -- Settings Box -- */
.modal {
 display: none; /* Hidden by default */
 position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
 z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%; /* Full width */
 height: 100%; /* Full height */
 overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
 background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black w/ opacity */

}

.modal-content {
 margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
 padding: 20px;
 width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
 border-radius: 10px;

}

.modal-content > h1, .modal-content p{
  color: #777;
}

.modal-content.light-mode{
  background-color: var(--page-light);
}

.modal-content.dark-mode{
  background-color: var(--page-dark);
}

.close {
 color: #aaa;
 float: right;
 font-size: 28px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
}

/* -- Toggle Switch -- */

input[type=checkbox]{
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 50px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #555;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 200px;
  position: relative;
}


label:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    left: -3px;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    background: var(--navbar-top);
    border-radius: 90px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

input:checked + label {
    background: var(--navbar-bottom);
}

input:checked + label:after {
    left: calc(100% + 3px);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

label:active:after {
    width: 30px;
}

/* -- Custom Colors -- */
#colors{
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
}

.color-change{
    display:inline-block;
    width:var(--cc-width);
    height:var(--cc-height);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.color-change:nth-child(1){
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--ccA-top), var(--ccA-bottom));
}

.color-change:nth-child(2){
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--ccB-top), var(--ccB-bottom));
}

.color-change:nth-child(3){
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--ccC-top), var(--ccC-bottom));
}

.color-change:nth-child(4){
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--ccD-top), var(--ccD-bottom));
}




@media screen and (min-width: 681px){
  .icon{
    line-height: var(--plus-h);
  }
  .icon > img{
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450) {
  .icon{
    height: 20vh;
    line-height: 20vh;

  }
  .icon > img{
    height: 20px;
    width: auto;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {

  nav{
    height: var(--navbar-dimension);
    width: 100vw;
  }

  nav:after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }

  .icon{
    float: left;
    width: var(--plus-w);
    height: 100%;
  }

  .icon > img{
    margin-top: calc((var(--navbar-dimension) - var(--icon-dimension))/2);
  }

}

::selection {
  background: var(--navbar-bottom);
  color: white;
}
::-moz-selection {
  background: var(--navbar-bottom);
  color: white;
}

h3::selection{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

body.light-mode{
  background-color: var(--body-light);
}
body.dark-mode{
  background-color: var(--body-dark);
}
```

Comment: This isn't how the `meta` tag is used. We really need to see the HTML and CSS to give an adequate answer. It's likely an issue with a media query if it's working fine on desktop.

Comment: I added some code.

Comment: I would check the file paths for your CSS. I changed it to a local file path on my device and it seems to be working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone **might** have not received all files and just had the HTML file.
When that happens, your HTML file won't change any styles cause it can't read the CSS files as they don't exist on your phone.
To be able to view the files on your phone, you can make sure the whole project folder is on the phone, and you open it from there. You can also use an inline styling approach (*adding `<style></style>` tags in your HTML file*) which is not recommended as you have a lot of CSS files.

I assume you use Atom text editor from the picture you sent, so you can use the [atom-live-server](https://atom.io/packages/atom-live-server) package and view it on your PC.
Why am I saying this? Because if you type `ipconfig` in your terminal, you can see the local IPv4 address of your PC on your local network. If both your PC and phone are connected to the same network, you can simply view the website in your phone by entering the URL `IPv4:PORT` where `IPv4` is your PC's local IPv4 address and `PORT` is the port the server is hosted on using atom-live-server. An example of the URL would be `192.168.1.1:3000`. This will allow you to view the website from any device connected to your network.

Comment: You might also have the files as Nick said in his comment to your question, but the paths to the CSS files are incorrect.

Comment: So why does my css work on desktop but not on phone if the path is not correct ?

Comment: Plus, I have a problem with atom-live-sever. I installed it, launched server on port 3000 and I am on the same network on my mobile. But my mobile can't access the site (it loads infinitely). I tried every different `192.196.X.X` showed in ipconfig. And on my computer it shows well the website when i type `192.168.43.119:3000/Off/html/common.html`

Comment: I meant the path is incorrect in your phone, it is correct on the desktop as you are in the same folder which has the files. On your phone, it might be different according to the location of the files. In atom-live-server, you can make sure first that the IPv4 is correct by entering the URL in your desktop first, and try entering the URL with no paths like `192.168.X.X:3000/`, which will give you an option to navigate through the files and folders from it.

Answer (score 0):

There couple of ways that you could do to bypass the error, try either.

Try embedding CSS into the HTML with style blocks. It's not a good practice but it solved my problem. I'm pretty sure you are trying to keep your code clean but it will still work.

also;

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen"/>
```

KIndly note that the forward-leaning backslash… (/)

finally, you can try using the web console t check the error. different browsers work differently.

Good Luck!

Comment: Sorry but I can't code css inside html files. My project is too big and it's an unprofessional way to correct the problem.

Comment: @MikeDelta I was just trying to help and let you out of the monster. Personally, I tried it and it works adding CSS on every container. All the best

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it matters on the phone you're using but shouldn't be semicolons in the `viewport` line. Should be:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 0):

use firefox and type location as file:///storage/path/to/file